# AWS Linux Instance: Access JBoss Wildfly console

Tags: amazon-web-services, wildfly

I am trying to start a JBoss Wildfly Application server in AWS Linux. As you can see in the log given below, the application server is started and it is listening in port 8080.

[image]

I got a descent response when I tried to **curl** to **http://localhost:8080/** from the same machine.

[image]

But while trying to access it from my laptop using the **IPv4 Public IP** it failed to connect throwing an error "**refused to connect**".

Given below are my security group settings.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what could be the possible reasons for this? Some people say that along with the security group settings, the firewall needs to be opened for this port too. But I am not sure how to do that as I am pretty new to AWS.

####UPDATE

I started a Tomcate server on the same instance and it is accessible outsite.
So is that something to do with the Wildfly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding all IP addresses to the wildfly as below
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tips to check issue.

1. Check if VPC is attached to Internet gateway ( In case you are not using Default VPC then you would need to attach one )
2. Check Network ACL's (Its on top for security group under VPC left side). 
   NACL's are stateless by nature and you need to add both Inbound and outbound rules to it.
   For Inbound rules you should open access to internet (Since you are accessing from Internet ) by adding 0.0.0.0/0 in destination and port 8080 
   For Outbound same for source address 0.0.0.0/0 and port you can choose all or ephemeral ports 1024 - 65535
3. check this NACL is attached to subnet where your EC2 instance resides.

Hope above steps help you to troubleshoot the problem.